# How to debug SqlDataSource

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

I'm testing my site against SQL injection attacks and I would like to trace SqlDataSource messages sent to SQL server. How can I do that or at least get as close as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlDataSource uses parametrized queries internally and normally that's enough for avoiding SQL Injection.

Here you an MSDN article to check

[How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it would.